# WPF Datagridrow change background color and checkbox value based on selected comobox item

Tags: wpf, combobox, binding, datagrid

Check out the screenshot via link provided below.

I've searched half the day but can not find any solution for my problem. The problem is:

When an item in de comobox is selected (for example: RBS), I want to change the background color of each row which contains RBS in the column 'Beschrijving' in the datagrid to green en check the checkbox in the first column.

Thank you so much in advance!

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIKQb.png)

Comment: You have to show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I did not know what language you are using, I am using Powershell for this example.

Lets break this problem into logical steps:

1. When `ComboBox` value is changed, iterate through all rows
2. While iterating, use the `ComboBox.Text` to match with **Beschrijving** column
3. If matched, change checkbox to `True`, change color of rows.
4. For items that don't match, change checkbox to `False` and reset colors.

There is definitely an easier way to do this, but here is a quick and dirty solution for you.

ComboBox has a `SelectedIndexChanged` event that we can use to determine if an option was selected.

Screenshot of final resut: [ComboBox Select Highlight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFr8k.png)

```
Function Edit-Row
{
    param(
        [String] $BColor = "White", $FColor = "Black",
        [Object] $DataGridView,
        [Int32] $Row,
        [Switch] $TickCheckbox
    )

    $BeshrijvingColumnIndex = 2
    $CheckboxIndex          = 0

    # Row Background / Cell Color
    $DataGridView.Rows[$Row].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromName($BColor)

    # Row Foreground / Text Color
    $DataGridView.Rows[$Row].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromName($FColor)

    # If Switch is Toggled, Tick Checkbox
    if($TickCheckbox)
    {
        $DataGridView.Rows[$Row].Cells[$CheckboxIndex].Value = $True
    }
}

$ComboBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$ComboBox.Items.Add("RBS")
$ComboBox.Items.Add("KIU")
$ComboBox.Items.Add("TBD")
$ComboBox.Items.Add("TBO")
$ComboBox.Items.Add("KIU")
$ComboBox.Add_SelectedIndexChanged({

    $BeshrijvingColumnIndex = 2
    $CheckboxIndex          = 0

    for($row = 0; $row -lt $DataGridView.RowCount; $row++)
    {
        # Value of cell at Row[row].Cells[Beshrijving]
        $CellData = $DataGridView.Rows[$row].Cells[$BeshrijvingColumnIndex].Value

        if($CellData -match $ComboBox.Text)
        {
            Edit-Row `
                -DataGridView $DataGridView `
                -Row $row `
                -BColor "Green" `
                -FColor "White" `
                -TickCheckbox
        }
        else
        {
            # Reset other rows back to initial state
            Edit-Row `
                -DataGridView $DataGridView `
                -Row $row
        }
    }
})
```

This code will highlight a row if **Column 2** contains the string from the option.

> P.S: You might want to not use `-match` keyword due to some values
>   containing similar tokes e.g. "TB", "TBD", "TBO", "TBL", if the
>   option was "TB", it would match all other tokes that start with "TB".